# Configurable Product Qty not working in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want change qty box in dropdown .So I'm override template file.`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Www_QtyDropdown::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

**addtocart.phtml**

```
    <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $qty = $block->getStockMaximumQty(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="box-tocart">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
                <div class="field qty">
                    <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <select name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" 
                                class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">
                                    <?php if ($qty > 4) { ?>
                                <option value = "0"></option>
                                <?php $i = 1; ?>                                
                                <?php while ($i <= 4) {
                                    ?>                            
                                    <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                                    <?php $i++; ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } else {
                                ?>
                                <option value = "0"></option>
                                <?php $i = 1;
                                ?>
                                <?php while ($i <= $qty) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                                    <?php $i++; ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

But is not working for configurable  product.If I need any modification in my code.

Comment: Have you checked the applied conditions in case configurable products? They should be true for them. Otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: How to check it....@Himmit

Comment: I meant; check the conditions <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?> and <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?> check if the value of $_product->isSaleable() and $block->shouldRenderQuantity() is not 0 for configurable products.

Comment: i'm added this code in my template <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>.still not working

Comment: both fun r return true

Answer (score 0):

Ok, please try adding below code in catalog_product_view.xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
       <action method="setTemplate">
          <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Www_QtyDropdown::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
       </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Already done it ....

Comment: it only gives dropdown....But the qty values  not fit here

Comment: Are you able to see dropdown?

Comment: For your information, in case configurable products, the parent product don't have qty. The qty is managed for product configurable options/child products.

Comment: Yes .But i trying to get child product id...I'm able to get all child product of configurable product.I don't know ..how to get selected child product id .....

Comment: It seems an issue with child products selection then.. :) Please set the right product and selection for qty to be displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70723/discussion-between-mahalakshmi-m-and-himmat-paliwal).